# MATLAB for loop adding i to the struct name

Tags: matlab, for-loop

From: [pass a struct through a loop to extract data and have the i in the loop added to the name](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1910955-pass-a-struct-through-a-loop-to-extract-data-and-have-the-i-in-the-loop-added-to-the-name?s_tid=srchtitle)

In this for loop:

```
for i = 1:length(pred_files)
    for j = 1:length(n_unknown)
        if predictions(1).pred_i.y_pred(j) == predictions(1).y_all(j)
            accuracy_totals(1).accuracy_total_i = accuracy_totals(1).accuracy_total_i +1
        end
    end
end
```

I want `i` to be added to the struct name; for example, on the first iteration, `predictions(1).pred_i` would be  `predictions(1).pred_1`.

Comment: Try: `predictions(1).(sprintf('pred_%d', i)) = predictions(1).y_all(j)`

Comment: You’re better off calling it `pred(i)`. So much simpler and shorter…

Comment: What @CrisLuengo said. Any time you find yourself trying to programmatically construct variable names with incrementing numbers in them, you should almost certainly be using some kind of array instead.